# Exclude directory from rewrite with mod_rewrite and lighttpd

Tags: configuration, mod-rewrite, lighttpd, zend-framework

Im migrating an apache2 server to Lighttpd, however im having some issues with Mod_Rewrite.

I have a directory /api/, which I need to exclude from the rewriting rules as follows:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    ".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",
    ".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$" => "$0",
    "" => "/index.php"
)
```

I have tried to surround the block with

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/api/" { }
```

However this has no effect and just excludes every URL from rewriting. Does anyone know of a way to

a) Exclude /api/ from the rewriting

b) exclude every actual directory present on the server from rewriting

I have seen Lua scripts for Drupal that can do the latter, however im not proficient in Lua and do not know how to configure this for a Zend Framework application.

Entire Configuration: http://pastebin.com/ggjiTFLk

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the first part**:

```
".*\?(.*)$"             => "/index.php?$1",
```

*to* `"^/(?!api[/]).*\?(.*)$"` **or** `"^/(?!api(?:$|/)).*\?(.*)$"`